# How to use Jsch to copy a file from a remote directory to another remote directory

Tags: java, jsch

I'd like to use Jsch to copy a file from a remote directory to another remote directory.

For now I've just done a simple ssh command: `cp remoteSource remoteDest` but is there a "better" way to accomplish that?

By better I mean a method in charge of doing it, in order to avoid potential mistakes or injection attacks while performing string manipulations.